# Adding className but css is not affecting in ReactJS Components

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called Single Box which will return a div , but i need to have the same class for 6 times , one of the way is i can write Single Box component six times , but thats not a good way.

So i made another component which Multiple Box , here i will loop the Single Box component for six times .

SingleBox

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="box-content"></div>
    )
  }
```

MultipleBox

```
 render(){
  let singleBoxArray = [];
   for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
     if(i< 2){
       singleBoxArray.push(<SingleBox key={i}/>);
     }else {
       singleBoxArray.push(<SingleBox className="box-three"/>)
     }
   }
    return(
      <div>
        {singleBoxArray}
      </div>
    )

    }
```

Here for the "Third SingleBox" , i need add one more class and it should affect the css. when i make the console.log("array" , singleBoxArray). For the third elememet i am getting the className in this.props, but my css is not changing .

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think you need the braces around "box-three"

Comment: I tried the className without curly braces , i updated it in the question too, But the style is not affecting.

Comment: can you see class getting added in DOM?

Comment: Do you want to keep both classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you don't need the curly braces for `className="box-three"`
second, what is the variable `singleBox` that you are returning in `render`, I can't find its declaration anywhere, maybe you meant to return the `singleBoxArray` instead

Comment: Yeah , my mistake. But still the css is not affecting. I updated the question.

Comment: Or else if i pass 

SingleBox

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="box-content box-three"></div>
    )
  }

and can i remove the className box-three for the First and Second SingleBox Component

Comment: by saying the css is not affecting you mean that the SingleBox comp is displaying with the first class properties only `box-content` ? or is it not showing any class? because when you push `<SingleBox className="box-three"/>`, you are not calling it anywhere in the `SingleBox` compnent, you should be doing somehitng like this in your SingleBox: `<div className=\`box-content ${this.props.className}\`></div>`

Comment: So is there any way to solve this. I knew but since i am calling this <MultipleBox /> for only one time in App.js, So the Multiple Box Component will render the Single Box for multiple times based on the for loop.

Comment: I tried in the template string but i am getting error
Syntax error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Comment: what is the error? and also please add the `key` property here also `else {
       singleBoxArray.push(<SingleBox key={i} className="box-three"/>)
     }`  , also you are not looping 6 times, but 4

Comment: yeah i wrapped in curly braces . thanks i will check and let you know

Comment: Thanks Elias Ghali . Worked for me

Comment: You are welcome, I would appreciate an upvote in this case

Answer (score 0):

**You are adding class to Component and not to DOM.**

So,thats why your CSS not showing effect.

Your `SingleBox` Component already attached with `box-content` class and you are not updating it.

In order to to update it,you need to attach class to DOM.

Use `props` for your custom class `myclass`

```
//SingleBox Component.

const SingleBox = (props) => (<div className={props.myclass}>Hello</div>);
```

//MultipleBox

```
render() {
    let singleBoxArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (i < 2) {
        singleBoxArray.push(<SingleBox key={i} myclass="box-content" />);
      } else {
        singleBoxArray.push(<SingleBox key={i} myclass="box-three" />)
      }
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {singleBoxArray}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SingleBox Component doesn't accept className as a prop.

it should be like this.

```
render(){
    const className = `box-content ${this.props.className}`
    return(
      <div className={className}></div>
    )
  }
```

And you can keep a default Prop for className as empty string

you can set defaultProps to a component by simply setting it like this before exporting.

```
SingleBox.defaultProps = {
  className: ''
}

export default SingleBox;
```

Comment: How can i set default prop as empty for className

Comment: I haved edited my answer to add example for that too

Comment: Thanks .It worked for me . So defaultProps is inbuild one of React

Comment: yes. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops